# Unable to launch firefox browser in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium

```
package newpackage;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class webdriver {
public static void main(String[] args){
//System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\Akash\\Downloads\\geckodriver-v0.18.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://google.com");

}

}
```

Getting below error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
>   org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to
>   localhost:18820 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]
>   failed: Connection refused: connect Build info: version: 'unknown',
>   revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'

Comment: why have u commented the geckodriver code? un-comment it and run it..

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try this,

1. Rename the geckodriver-v0.18.0-win64 folder without any special characters and spaces and try again.
2. Else download the gecko driver again and check.

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Update the selenium jar files as you are using updated gecko may solve your issues

And as I see you commented setProperty method, then make sure that you are using jar below 2.53 and ff version below 47.

Otherwise if you used jars above this.you have to use updated gecko driver.